# How count common elements for every combination of rows in a matrix?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to count the common elements among each combination of rows in a dataset. I manage to do it with a nested loop which works fine for a small dataset but for the real one (1380*1380 combinations) takes too long. I wonder if there is a straightforward and less computation intensive way to do it.

```
a <- c(1,5,6,8,9) 
b <- c(4,3,6,8,2)
c <- c(4,3,6,1,9)
df <- rbind(a,b,c)
```

Result should look like this

```
data.frame(p1= c('a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c'), 
           p2= c('a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c'), 
           res= c(5,2,2,2,5,3,2,3,5))
```

If it takes out comparisons between self would be even better.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Can you detail a little bit the example?
I can't figure why the first row of the output is `1 1 5`:
the first two column contain the cartesian product of the distinct elements of the dataset, right?
But I really can't understand the `5`...

Comment: @RobertoB did you run your loop and time it? I mean it's a pretty heavy operation no matter what so maybe some benchmark would be good?

Comment: Sorry if not clear @Bruno, the `5` stands for the number of elements in common between the two rows (1 and 1 in this case) .

Comment: @friep i did some benchmark on the first 13 rows of my dataset and these are the results: `option 1 (my loop) - rep: 100, elapsed: 4.43`;  `option 2 (as suggested by`@Sotos `-rep: 100; elapsed: 16.58 `

Answer (score 2):

You can do this fairly quickly for all combinations (including a x a) using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

# Set up data.table
DT <- data.table(p = c("a","b","c"), vec = c(list(a), list(b), list(c)))
DT[, JA := 1]
DT <- merge(DT, DT, by = "JA", allow.cartesian = TRUE)

# calculate intersection
DT[, length(intersect(unlist(vec.x),unlist(vec.y))), by = .(p.x, p.y)]
   p.x p.y V1
1:   a   a  5
2:   a   b  2
3:   a   c  3
4:   b   a  2
5:   b   b  5
6:   b   c  3
7:   c   a  3
8:   c   b  3
9:   c   c  5
```

The one thing that may be tricky with your data will be initializing your data.table with a list column, but that will depend how your 1380 vectors are currently stored.

To filter out a x a, just use:

```
DT[p.x != p.y]
```

This solution is very fast, processing 1 million rows in ~12 seconds

```
DT2 <- data.table(p.x = 1:1000000, p.y = 1:1000000)
DT2[, vec.x := rep(list(a), 1e6)]
DT2[, vec.y := rep(list(b), 1e6)]

system.time(DT2[, length(intersect(unlist(vec.x),unlist(vec.y))), by = .(p.x, p.y)])
user  system elapsed 
11.80    0.03   12.00
```

EDIT: after re-reading your example, interesction may not be what you need. If the order of the elements is important, use the following instead:

```
DT[, length(which(unlist(vec.x) == unlist(vec.y))), by = .(p.x, p.y)]
   p.x p.y V1
1:   a   a  5
2:   a   b  2
3:   a   c  2
4:   b   a  2
5:   b   b  5
6:   b   c  3
7:   c   a  2
8:   c   b  3
9:   c   c  5
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems indeed a nice solution. I am working on it because as you said the tricky part is in get the data as list of columns

Comment: This one does not work if the data in each vector has a different length.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the same rows to be compared (i.e. a with a), then `combn` can work as follows,

```
combn(1:nrow(df), 2, FUN = function(i) sum(df[i[1],] - df[i[2],]==0))
#[1] 2 2 3

# or add the names of combinations as well,

setNames(combn(1:3, 2, FUN = function(i) sum(df[i[1],] - df[i[2],]==0)), 
         combn(rownames(df), 2, toString))
#a, b a, c b, c 
#   2    2    3
```

Comment: i arrived at a similar solution (which i won't post as yours is the same basically) but maybe add `df1 <- df1[df1$Var1 != df1$Var2, ]` to take out the "comparisons to self" the OP talked of? for the small example, it doesn't matter much but with 1200 rows it takes out approx 60000 comparisons. :)

Comment: @friep I missed the "Take out comparison between itself". Thanks for pointing it out. I will revise :)

Comment: I think you may want `length(which(df[i[1],] == df[i[2],]))` instead to align with his example, since position of the values is important. I made the same error below.

Comment: @Chris the one with `combn` is already aligned...no? (BTW, very nice answer you provided!!!)

Comment: Yes sorry that one is right - I mean the second example you provided

Comment: Actually I ll delete that one. Can't stand the `apply(.., margin = 1, ..)` thing