# How to make a count matrix of common elements across many groups?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, combinations

I'm trying to identify common elements across multiple vectors, with all combinations possible.
I had previously tried [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44964358/how-count-common-elements-for-every-combination-of-rows-in-a-matrix), but it doesn't quite work out because it only retrieves the common elements between 2 groups.

Take this example: I have 10 vectors (varying in number of elements) that may have common elements with one or more other vectors. It is also possible that some elements are exclusive to some groups. As an example, here is the data:

```
#Creating a mock example: 10 groups, with varying number of elements:
set.seed(753)
for (i in 1:10){
  assign(paste0("grp_",i), paste0("target_", sample(1:40, sample(20:34))))
}
```

Simply put, I want to **do something analogous to a Venn diagram, but put into a data frame/matrix** with the counts, instead. Something like this (*note that here, I am just adding a snapshot of random parts of how the result data frame/matrix should look like*):

```
                                                   grp1 grp2 grp3 grp4 grp1.grp4.grp5.grp8.grp10
grp1                                                 -    16   12   20                         5
grp2                                                 16    -   10   20                         4
grp3                                                 12   10    -   16                         3
grp4                                                 20   20   16    -                         5
grp1.grp4.grp5.grp8.grp10                             5    4    3    5                        10
grp1.grp2.grp3.grp4.grp5.grp6.grp7.grp8.grp9.grp10    0    0    0    0                         0
                                                   grp1.grp2.grp3.grp4.grp5.grp6.grp7.grp8.grp9.grp10
grp1                                                                                                3
grp2                                                                                                6
grp3                                                                                                4
grp4                                                                                                1
grp1.grp4.grp5.grp8.grp10                                                                           5
grp1.grp2.grp3.grp4.grp5.grp6.grp7.grp8.grp9.grp10                                                  2
```

From the table above, please also note that counts that have the same row and column names mean that they are exclusive to that particular group (e.g. count on row1/col1 means that there are 88 exclusive elements).

Any help is very much appreciated!

EDIT: the real counts for the expected final matrix has now been added.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to have a sample output that *does* match the test input so that we can confirm the accuracy of our proposed solutions.

Comment: Thank you @Limey, an sorry for not adding the real expected result at first. I made the calculations manually (```intersect``` for each combination it is) and have included them now. But I'd also like to reiterate that this is the snapshot of the expected final table/matrix, as the final matrix should be larger (containing all possible combinations).

Comment: When I try to run your code I get an Error. `Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : invalid 'size' argument`. Could you please double check that your code works to generate the sample data? (Maybe you need the `size = 1` in `sample(20:34, size = 1)`?)

Comment: (I'd also suggest putting everything in a `list` rather than using `assign`.... the first step of any answer will probably be to put all your stray vectors into a `list` to work with them more easily.)

Comment: See set operations in base R: https://rdrr.io/r/base/sets.html  They perform the member groupings of a Venn diagram.

Comment: So if I understand it well you want a 1023 x 1023 sized matrix for all combinations and the counts?

Comment: Thank you most of all trying to genuinely help!
@Gregor Thomas: I just re-run the lines and it ran fine. The second ```sample()``` function, I added to show that my groups vary in number of elements. Is it possible that the lines might have not been copied completely?

Comment: Hi, @Steve, you got to the exact point. I actually used ```intersect()``` manually to reproduce the expected matrix above. However, because the final matrix is quite large, it becomes quite cumbersome to do it manually for all possible combination. Plus, the chance for error increases. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, @Merijin van Tilborg, exactly! Any idea on how I can perform this? (:

Comment: @Douglas did you copy/paste the code from your question and run it? The little snippet `sample(1:40, sample(20:34))` definitely causes an error using the built-in `base::sample`. Maybe you have a package loaded that provides a different `sample` function? See where `?sample` takes you and if it's the `base` package or not.

Comment: @Douglas not sure yet, as I am not 100% sure on your counts, simply doing manually: `sum(grp_1 %in% grp_2) #12
sum(grp_1 %in% grp_3) # 19
sum(grp_1 %in% grp_4) # 15` I would have expected those counts and not as you show in your desired output 16, 12, 20

Comment: @Douglas generating your combinations can be done like this `N <- 10
unlist(sapply(1:N, function(n) combn(1:N, n, simplify = F)), recursive = F)` and perhaps add your groups as a list, like grps[1]-grps[10], then you have in the combinations all numbers you go over and sum the existance in all grps there. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Seconding Gregor Thomas.  The code above throws an error: Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : invalid 'size' argument  So it is not clear what you are a trying to generate.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @Gregor Thomas and @SteveM, thank you again. That's quite weird. I checked that again, and just to make sure the it was calling the ```base:sample()``` function, I tried:
```set.seed(142);
base::sample(1:40, base::sample(20:34))
```
And it returned this:
```[1] 21  8 11  7  1 15 27 24 34 37 26 12 13 14 17 29 18  3 32  2 30 35 19 31  9  4 40 38 16 22 25 20
```

Anything that might have been missed along the way?

Comment: Hmmm, looking at the R release notes in version 4.2.0 included *`sample()` and `sample.int()` have additional sanity checks on their size and n arguments*--so maybe you're running a version of R before that and it silently ignores `size` inputs > 1 and just uses the first value. If you switch to `sample(1:40, sample(20:34, size = 1))` it should be equivalent (though to keep the results the same with the seed `sample(1:40, sample(20:34)[1])` might be safer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if I understood all well, lets give it a try. Note that I added your sample data in a list, so we can index them to intersect.

```
set.seed(753)
grps <- list()
for (i in 1:10){
  grps[i] <- list(paste0("target_", sample(1:40, sample(20:34))))
}
```

You want all 10 groups resulting in 1023 x 1023 combinations
Making it flexible makes testing a bit easier ;)
The key here is I keep them as list with integers that we can index in grps.

```
N <- 10
combinations <- unlist(sapply(1:N, function(n) combn(1:N, n, simplify = F)), recursive = F)
```

Now we have to loop twice over your combinations as you compare each 1023 x 1023 combinations with their intersects. The use of sapply gives us the nice 1023 x 1023 matrix you want.

```
results <- sapply(seq_along(combinations), function(i) {

 sapply(seq_along(combinations), function(j) {
   
    length(intersect(
      Reduce(intersect, grps[combinations[[i]]]),
      Reduce(intersect, grps[combinations[[j]]])
    ))
   
  })

})
```

Now we create the names as shown in your example, they are based on the combinations we created and used earlier.

```
names <- sapply(combinations, function(x) paste("grp", x, sep = "", collapse = "."))
```

Create the colnames and rownames of the matrix

```
colnames(results) <- rownames(results) <- names
```

Seems in your output you want to values for the diagonals, so we change that to NA

```
diag(results) <- NA
```

Comment: That worked nicely! Thank you very much, @Merijn van Tilborg.
And if, by any chance, somebody in the future is trying that out as well, with this size (or larger) of matrix, bear in mind that it does take some time to run it. Otherwise, it works super good. Thank you again.